How to check similarities between two datasets and return a score in Snowflake (is it even possible?)
I have two data sets containing full names of my company customers. Both sets are rather large (40-70k rows). I would like to check if there are similarities between the two groups. For example: if one set has a record with the value 'John Smith' and the other 'John W. Smith' I'd like to possibly consider it as a match.



Column A
Column B
Similarity Score




John Smith
John W. Smith
0.97


James Bond
Andrew Bond
0.5



The data sets have different size, they are on Snowflake . Let me know if any information is missing.
Also, do you think that this is solvable with SQL? Or is Python more suitable?
I tried using Jarowinkler similarity but it applies only to 'specific' strings, not to datasets.


JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY 2. Vector Embeddings & VECTOR_COSINE_SIMILARITY


Snowflake has a couple of functions for fuzzy string matching, like editdistance and soundex.  I'm sure there are plenty of python libraries for this.

You can use fuzzywuzzy library in Pyhton, Did you check?

You should prep and clean the data before comparing similarity. Below is one approach using Snowflake SQL.
WITH table_a_prepped AS (
  SELECT
      name,
      -- Remove suffixes/titles, characters not alphabet or space, normalize case and trim
      TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(TRIM(name)), '[A-Z ]', ''), '^(MR|MRS|MISS|MS|DR|PROF)',''),'(JR\.|SR\.|II|III|IV)$','')) AS first_clean,
      -- Remove middle names or initials
      CASE
        WHEN ARRAY_SIZE(SPLIT(first_clean, ' ')) > 2 THEN SPLIT_PART(first_clean, ' ', 1) || ' ' || SPLIT_PART(first_clean, ' ', -1)
        ELSE first_clean
      END AS cleaned_name,
      -- Create blocking key using the first letters of the first and last names from the cleansed name
       SUBSTRING(SPLIT_PART(cleaned_name,' ', 1), 1, 1) || SUBSTRING(SPLIT_PART(cleaned_name,' ', -1), 1, 1) AS blocking_key
    FROM
      table_a
  ),
  table_b_prepped AS (
    SELECT
      name,
      -- Remove suffixes/titles, characters not alphabet or space, normalize case and trim
      TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(TRIM(name)), '[^A-Z ]', ''), '^(MR|MRS|MISS|MS|DR|PROF)',''),'(JR\.|SR\.|II|III|IV)$','')) AS first_clean,
      -- Remove middle names or initials
      CASE
        WHEN ARRAY_SIZE(SPLIT(first_clean, ' ')) > 2 THEN SPLIT_PART(first_clean, ' ', 1) || ' ' || SPLIT_PART(first_clean, ' ', -1)
        ELSE first_clean
      END AS cleaned_name,
      -- Create blocking key using the first letters of the first and last names from the cleansed name
       SUBSTRING(SPLIT_PART(cleaned_name,' ', 1), 1, 1) || SUBSTRING(SPLIT_PART(cleaned_name,' ', -1), 1, 1) AS blocking_key
    FROM
      table_b
  )
  SELECT
    a.name AS "Column A",
    b.name AS "Column B",
    -- Levenshtein Distance converted to a similarity score between 0 and 1
    1 - (EDITDISTANCE(a.cleaned_name, b.cleaned_name)::FLOAT / GREATEST(LENGTH(a.cleaned_name), LENGTH(b.cleaned_name))) AS "Similarity Score"
  FROM
    table_a_prepped AS a
  INNER JOIN
    table_b_prepped b ON a.blocking_key = b.blocking_key
  
      

